# Aligning top half of landscape longtable to inner margin

Tags: longtable, afterpage, threeparttablex, lscape

Is it possible to align the first part of the landscape longtable to the page inner margin? I would like the table to be centered on the page pair when I turn my book 90 degrees to read the table.

[image: Output with annotation]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\pagestyle{showlocs}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
  \mainmatter
  \chapter{A chapter}
  \Blindtext[3]
  \section{A section}
  \Blindtext[7]
  \afterpage{\begin{landscape}
    \begin{ThreePartTable}
      \begin{TableNotes}
        \item[a] \label{tn:a} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        \item[b] \label{tn:b} Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        \source Made up
      \end{TableNotes}
      \begin{longtable}{l l l}
        \caption{A long table}\\
        \toprule
        Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes\\
        \endlastfoot
        First line\tnotex{tn:a} & 123 & 456 \\
        Second line\tnotex{tn:b} & 123 & 456 \\
        Third line & 123 & 456 \\
        Fourth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Fifth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Sixth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Seventh line & 123 & 456 \\
        Eighth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Nineth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Tenth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Eleventh line & 123 & 456 \\
        Twelfth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Thirteenth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Fourteenth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Fifteenth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Sixteenth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Seventeenth line & 123 & 456 \\
        \newpage
        Eighteenth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Nineteenth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Twentieth line & 123 & 456 \\
      \end{longtable}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
  \end{landscape}}
  \Blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry if the question isn't exactly crystal clear. I feel that I lack the proper terminology to express this...